# Laravel Edit link doesn't work

Tags: laravel

Every post in the list has `Edit` link

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('dashboard/post/' . $post->id . '/edit') }}" class="btn btn-default btn-edit-post">Edit</a>
```

routes

```
Route::get('dashboard/posts/{id}/edit', 'PostsController@edit');
Route::put('dashboard/posts/{id}', 'PostsController@update');
```

methods in `PostsController`

```
    public function edit($id) 
    {
        $post = Post::findOrFail($id);  
        return view('dashboard.edit', compact('post'));
    }

    public function update($id, PostRequest $request) 
    {
        $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
        $post->update($request->all());
        return redirect ('dashboard');
    }
```

but on clink on the Edit button I get an error

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

What's wrong? How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the route file you have written posts and in the href post

{{ URL::to('dashboard/**post**/' . $post->id . '/edit') }}

Route::get('dashboard/**posts**/{id}/edit', 'PostsController@edit');

Comment: Ouch!.. Thank you very much!